# remote jQuery Template not rendering

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-templates

Hi I am very new jQuery template, I am not able to fetch templates from remote folders but its working fine when I am using inline templates. My HTML is

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="category_head">Heading..</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="category-video-container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now my template file is: **_category.tmpl.html**

```
<script id="categoryTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
        <a class="videos_display" href="#"> <img src="${imgUrl}" />
            <div class="xyz">${xyz}</div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="title">${name}</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
```

and my js file is

```
 var categories = [
   { name: "Anchorman 1: Fight Scene", xyz: '13:00', imgUrl: "assets/images/Desert.jpg" },
   { name: "Anchorman 2: Fight Scene", xyz: '13:00', imgUrl: "assets/images/Lighthouse.jpg" },
   { name: "Anchorman 3: Fight Scene", xyz: '13:00', imgUrl: "assets/images/Penguins.jpg" },
   { name: "Anchorman 4: Fight Scene", xyz: '13:00', imgUrl: "assets/images/Tulips.jpg" }
];

$.get("_category.tmpl.html", null, function(categoryTemplate) {
    $(categoryTemplate).tmpl( categories ).appendTo( "#category-video-container" );
});
```

Please help

Comment: Can you try like this.added find with id name.                                                     `$.get("_category.tmpl.html", null, function(categoryTemplate) {
    $(categoryTemplate).find("#categoryTemplate").tmpl( categories ).appendTo( "#category-video-container" );
});`